# Questions involving lists

Tags: discussion

I think that some question involving list are actually good *this site* (not that the baseline level of objectiveness is shifted with respect to e.g. SO), as:

- objective,
- useful,
- of general interest,
- *not* chatty.

For example, I consider this question:

- https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36/what-citation-manager-should-i-use (perhaps up to the wording like "use" vs "list of")

much better than

- [Is it worth to switch from Bibsonomy to Mendeley?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/365/is-it-worth-to-switch-from-bibsonomy-to-mendeley).

Moreover, discouraging questions of the first type will generate a lot of questions of the second type (roughly $n(n-1)/2$, where $n$ is number of apps).

In case of doubts - look at the answer the question generates.

Do you agree with such point?

Answer (score 3):

List-based questions can serve as a useful tool, so long as they encourage answers that are *explanatory*. A simple collection of web links should not be our goal; curation and explanation fo why links are useful will go a lot further.

As you said, list questions can replace the large number of "Should I do X or Y"-type questions, and in that sense can be valuable, especially if the question is likely to come up anyways.

We should be vigilant to make sure that list-based questions contribute value, rather than just lead to sprawling lists of links.